Split Videos using File Size in ffmpeg
How do I split videos by file size using ffmpeg? For example, I have a 1.92GB video and I want to split it into 200MB videos. There are two ways how I want to split them:

Losslessly by using the -c copy parameter
At non-keyframes/frames other than I-frames while re-encoding into other video formats like H.264.

The problem is, when I used the -fs parameter to split videos, I only got one file. How do I fix that.
Command line: ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -fs 200M output_segment_%03d.mp4

You can't split by size, only by time, using the segment muxer.

Then what does?
